# XCode XCAssets and autocompletion

Tags: xcode, xcasset

I was wondering if anyone knew if the XCAsset symbols provided in autocompletion can be used in any way, I imagine something but it didn't worked.

[image]

Xcode propose all the images, it looks really interesting but if it's just to "show" I would be sad :(

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing there is an *image literal*. It's not the name for the image, it *is* the image — so using one is equivalent to the *entire* `UIImage(named: "icon-stack")` call, not just the `"icon-stack"` string within that call.

If you assign one of these directly to a `var` or `let`, you'll see that its inferred type is `UIImage` (or `NSImage` if targeting macOS):

[image: image literal inferred type]

Comment: Maybe you can confirm me, but it seems to work only with Swift 3.0

Comment: Yes, image literals (for asset catalogs in an Xcode project) are for Swift 3 only. Image literals in general have been around longer, but before Xcode 8 / Swift 3 could be used only in playgrounds.